# Proving that $n^5 \equiv n\mod 30$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ a natural number non zero

Prove that: $$n^5 \equiv n\mod 30$$

I have tried to use fermat theorem and little fermat i can't find any result

Comment: $n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=(n-1)n(n+1)(n^2+1)$. The first three factors guarantee a factor of 6. Consider what happens modulo 5.

Answer (score 2):

First, $n^5 - n$ is a multiple of 5 according to Fermat's Little Theorem. Second, $n^5 - n$ is a multiple of 2, because $n^5$ has the same pairty as $n$. Finally, $n^5 - n$ is a multiple of 3: if $n$ is divisible by 3 then $n^5 - n$ is also divisible by 3; if $n \equiv 1$ then $n^5 \equiv n \equiv 1$ and if $n \equiv 2$ then $n^5 \equiv n \equiv 2$.

Thus, $n^5 - n$ is a multiple of $5 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 30$.

Comment: when you write "$n^5$ has the same **oddity** as $n$," the word you want is "parity," not "oddity."

Comment: @symplectomorphic sure, thanks! Fixed now.